# How many times can I feed as a Vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering if I turned into a vampire in Skyrim, how many times can I feed in order to turn myself back to stage 1?

I am under the assumption that NPCs don't respawn, so there must be a hard limit to the number of times I can feed on them to turn myself back to stage 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no limits to how many times you can feed as a vampire. Feeding on an NPC won't lower the health of or kill the NPC. Also, there's no need to feed multiple times at one feeding interval, as feeding *once* always returns you to stage one vampirism.

More info at the [UESP wiki's "Vampirism" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism)